# Как правильно сохранить(создать) файл в тестах Django в setUp

Tags: django, юнит-тесты

Как правильно сохранить(создать) файл в тестах Django в setUp. Надо сохранить список файлов в setUp. Мой вариант не работает. Кто может подсказать?
Мой вариант

```
        self.test_gallery_images_one = GalleryImage.objects.create(
            gallery_id=self.test_gallery_one,
            photo=[
            'C:/Python Progs/PythonProjects/Django/coomo-website/media/gallery/1/zp3vALSsgDc.jpg',
            'C:/Python Progs/PythonProjects/Django/coomo-website/media/gallery/1/sjz-COq95j0.jpg',
            'C:/Python Progs/PythonProjects/Django/coomo-website/media/gallery/1/CsakTaFqoD4.jpg'])
```

Ошибка:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
........E....
======================================================================
ERROR: test_gallery_list (gallery.tests.TestGallery)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python Progs\PythonProjects\Django\coomo-website\gallery\tests.py", line 20, in setUp
    self.test_gallery_images_one = GalleryImage.objects.create(
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method    
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method    
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1409, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1352, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1353, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1353, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1304, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 299, in pre_save
    if file and not file._committed:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_committed'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 13 tests in 0.358s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

models.py

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Название галлереи')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Описание галлереи')
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        default=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Автор')


class GalleryImage(models.Model):
    gallery_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Gallery,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Название галлереи',
        help_text='Выберите к какой галлерее будет принадлежать картинка',
        related_name='photos')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_to, verbose_name='Картинка')
```

Comment: Покажите для начало свой вариант.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Окей, просто думал, что так будет выглядеть нормально

Comment: @asanisimov Выше добавил

Comment: @RomanKonoval Обновил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приблизительно так:

```
for path in [
    'C:/Python Progs/PythonProjects/Django/coomo-website/media/gallery/1/zp3vALSsgDc.jpg',
    'C:/Python Progs/PythonProjects/Django/coomo-website/media/gallery/1/sjz-COq95j0.jpg',
    'C:/Python Progs/PythonProjects/Django/coomo-website/media/gallery/1/CsakTaFqoD4.jpg']:

    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        GalleryImage.objects.create(
            gallery_id=self.test_gallery_one, photo=ImageFile(f)
        )
```

Вот только сохранить все это в одну переменную, как у вас делается с `self.test_gallery_images_one` получится только если превратить ее в список,  ведь вы создаете не один, а три файла.

Comment: Окей, Спасибо, попробую